# Warning message: In garch(lpr, order = c(2, 1)) : singular information

Tags: r, time-series, regression, warnings

I was trying to run the GARCH model on the currency exchange rates EUR/USD.

`lpr` stands for log price return.

When running the code:

```
garch(lpr, order = c(2, 1))
```

I am getting the following warning:

> Warning message: In garch(lpr, order = c(2, 1)) : singular information

Does anyone know what should I be cautious of? What does the warning message mean?

Comment: I assume you're using the `garch` function from the `tseries` package?  Can you give us some more information about `lpr`? What do you see when you use the command `str(lpr)`? According to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tseries/versions/0.10-42/topics/garch) it needs to be a numeric vector or timeseries.

Comment: @Numb3rs It's basically a price change, which are usually numeric values between -1 and 1. For example:

`str(lpr)
num [1:4658] 0.000734 -0.005153 -0.008151 -0.003727 0.000747 ...`

`summary(lpr)
       Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-0.1026541 -0.0051151  0.0000000 -0.0002756  0.0035619  0.0720969`